Copy $match result in a pipeline
My use case for output of the aggregation query:
[{
  items: <ALL_FILTERED_DOCUMENTS>,
  count: <ALL_DOCUMENTS_LENGTH>
}]

I did a try with `$facet`:
db.collection(<COLLECTION>).aggregate([
  { $facet: { items: [{ $match: <FILTER> }] } },
  {
    $project: {
      items: { $slice: ['$items', <SKIP>, <LIMIT>] },
      count: { $size: '$items' }
    }
  }
])

but, with a big collection, I got the error:

PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: document constructed by $facet is 1049500 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes

What should I use to set items equals to result of $match avoiding $facet?
Edit:
I did a try with $group:
db.collection(<COLLECTION>).aggregate([
  { $match: <FILTER> },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: { $push: '$$ROOT' },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      items: { $slice: ['$items', <SKIP>, <LIMIT>] },
      count: { $size: '$items' }
    }
  }
])

and I got the error:

PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Used too much memory for a single array. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes. The array contains <ITEMS_LENGTH> elements and is of size <ITEMS_SIZE> bytes. The element being added has size <ITEM_SIZE> bytes.

Solution (source):
db.collection(<COLLECTION>).aggregate([
  { $match: <FILTER> },
  { $sort: { <FIELD>: 1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      count: [{ $count: 'count' }],
      items: [
        { $skip: <SKIP> },
        { $limit: <LIMIT> },
        { $project: { <FIELD>: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  }
])


Does this answer your question? Pagination of facet pipelines. Perform the $facet after $match

$facet has the limit of 104857600 bytes, I can't use it.

likely your $match is not selective enough and included too many results. What are you trying to achieve?

I have a big collection and I need to filter documents, count them and return a page.

How about having a smaller page size?

The $size is used in $project and the issue is in previous pipeline where documents are filtered. The steps are:

save $match result in a value (items)
count items (with $size) and get the page ($slice)


You cannot return all the matched data if there are too many. That is why pagination exists to solve this kind of problem. You have to return a smaller subset of data.

I return the page ($match result limited with $slice)

See if this answer helps

That is a very inefficient way to paginate.  Combining the count query with the page query like that turns this query into a scan of the full collection.  If you separate those into 2 separate queries, you could significantly improve performance.

Rather than pushing all the documents to the same array and then slicing, you can employ the $match and $limit stages directly for paginating your data.
db.collection(<COLLECTION>).aggregate([
  { $match: <FILTER> },
  { $skip: <SKIP> },
  { $limit: <LIMIT> },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      items: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: <COLLECTION>,
      pipeline: [
        { $match: <FILTER> },
        { $count: "count" }
      ],
      as: "totalCount"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      items: 1,
      count: { $arrayElemAt: ["$totalCount.count", 0] }
    }
  }
])

